# How to Detect Select n+1 problems in Linq to SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

What is the best way to detect Select n+1 problems if i am using linq to SQL, right now we are working on a project and it seem to be pretty slow to display some lists. 
What is the best method to detect this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/11/13/linq-to-sql-profiler-is-now-on-public-beta.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/d5a64d5a-174a-4357-ad84-dbeeec030f23

Or you can use SQL Profiler and just check if queries are executed when you access individual list items.

Answer (score 2):

This won't outright detect n+1 problems, but they're pretty easy to spot when you look at your generated SQL.

The DataContext.Log property takes a TextWriter that will output the generated SQL and some other diagnostic information. Here's an implementation that logs to the output. [Linq to SQL DebuggerWriter](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kris/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11). Here's the simple example of how to use the DebuggerWriter.

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
#if DEBUG
db.Log = new DebuggerWriter();
#endif
```