# C# LINQ MySQL Query optimisation

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Using LINQ to MySQL

**MySQL TABLE Definition**

```
ID              binary(16) PK
UtcTriggerTime  datetime NOT NULL
PersonID        binary(16) NOT NULL FK
Status          int(11) NOT NULL
```

I have a array of **1000s** of PersonIDs(Guids) and for each of the PersonID I would like to pick matching records from the table with the following criteria:

```
UtcTriggerTime >= PREDEFINED_DATE_TIME (e.g. UtcNow - 30days)
AND 
Status=1 OR Status=2
```

I am currently using a

```
foreach(var personID in personIDsArray){
        var qryResult = (from a in AlertObjects.AlertsTriggered
                               where a.PersonID == personID &&
                               (a.Status == 1 || a.Status == 2) &&
                               a.UtcTriggerTime  >= PREDEFINED_DATE_TIME                                   
                               select a).ToArray();
}
```

What are the possible options to optimise this for performance? Or is there?

I tried putting an Index on (UtcTriggerTime, PersonID, Status) and then used the array of PersonIDs to do it in one query as follows, but it was even slower which when I thought about makes sense:

```
        var qryResult = (from a in AlertObjects.AlertsTriggered
                               where personIDsArray.Contains(a.PersonID) &&
                               (a.Status == 1 || a.Status == 2) &&
                               a.UtcTimeTriggered >= PREDEFINED_DATE_TIME
                               group a by a.PersonID into alerts
                               select alerts).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are dealing with typical Select N+1 problem which is caused by

```
group a by a.PersonID into alerts
select alerts
```

part.
Could you look in the generated SQL and see what it looks like?

Also there is no need to put Status in index if there not many values because the increase on the performance will be minimal.

If my quess is right you can look on these question to see how the problem can be handled:

[How to Detect Select n+1 problems in Linq to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771226/how-to-detect-select-n1-problems-in-linq-to-sql) 
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Oct/12/LINQ-to-SQL-Lazy-Loading-and-Prefetching


I'm not familiar with MySql but it seems to me that this link could be helpful in diagnosing which queries are slow.
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-running-queries-mysql/

Comment: Thank you Jenea. The SQL generated by LINQ is way too big becauae the number of IDs in the contains clause. Also in my command window it gets clipped although I guess there must be a way round that

Comment: run with a smaller number of user ids. Query plan should be the same (not sure though) and you'll be able to see what's going on.